# ValueError: `run` not supported when there is not exactly one output key. Got ['answer', 'sources', 'source_documents']. (langchain/Streamlit)

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain, py-langchain

I got an error says

```
ValueError: `run` not supported when there is not exactly one output key. Got ['answer', 'sources', 'source_documents'].
```

Here's the traceback error

```
File "C:\Users\Science-01\anaconda3\envs\gpt-dev\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 565, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "C:\Users\Science-01\Documents\Working Folder\Chat Bot\Streamlit\alpha-test.py", line 67, in <module>
    response = chain.run(prompt, return_only_outputs=True)
File "C:\Users\Science-01\anaconda3\envs\gpt-dev\lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\base.py", line 228, in run
    raise ValueError(
```

I tried to run langchain on Streamlit. I use `RetrievalQAWithSourcesChain` and `ChatPromptTemplate`

Here is my code

```
import os

import streamlit as st

from apikey import apikey

from langchain.document_loaders import PyPDFLoader
from langchain.document_loaders import DirectoryLoader
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.vectorstores import Chroma
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQAWithSourcesChain
from langchain.llms import OpenAI

from langchain.prompts.chat import (
    ChatPromptTemplate,
    SystemMessagePromptTemplate,
    HumanMessagePromptTemplate,
)

from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI

os.environ['OPENAI_API_KEY'] = apikey

st.title(' OpenAI Testing')
prompt = st.text_input('Put your prompt here')

loader = DirectoryLoader('./',glob='./*.pdf', loader_cls=PyPDFLoader)
pages = loader.load_and_split()

text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(
    chunk_size = 1000,
    chunk_overlap  = 200,
    length_function = len,
)

docs = text_splitter.split_documents(pages)
embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()

docsearch = Chroma.from_documents(docs, embeddings)

system_template = """
Use the following pieces of context to answer the users question.
If you don't know the answer, just say that "I don't know", don't try to make up an answer.
----------------
{summaries}"""

messages = [
    SystemMessagePromptTemplate.from_template(system_template),
    HumanMessagePromptTemplate.from_template("{question}")
]
prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(messages)

chain_type_kwargs = {"prompt": prompt}
llm = ChatOpenAI(model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo", temperature=0, max_tokens=256)  # Modify model_name if you have access to GPT-4
chain = RetrievalQAWithSourcesChain.from_chain_type(
    llm=llm,
    chain_type="stuff",
    retriever=docsearch.as_retriever(search_kwargs={'k':2}),
    return_source_documents=True,
    chain_type_kwargs=chain_type_kwargs
)

if prompt:
    response = chain.run(prompt, return_only_outputs=True)
    st.write(response)
```

It seems like the error is in `chain.run()`, anyone know how to solve this error? Thanks!

Comment: Use `predict()` or just enter arguments into `chain()` directly.  Make sure you have Python 3.8+.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76199653/valueerror-run-not-supported-when-there-is-not-exactly-one-input-key-got-q/76203995#76203995) post

Comment: Can you try removing .run. See this [doc](https://python.langchain.com/en/latest/modules/chains/index_examples/vector_db_qa.html), when they are returning source, they are not using .run Also look at [this](https://python.langchain.com/en/latest/modules/chains/index_examples/vector_db_qa_with_sources.html), its not using .run

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution, change this code

```
if prompt:
    response = chain.run(prompt, return_only_outputs=True)
    st.write(response)
```

to this

```
if st.button('Generate'):
    if prompt:
        with st.spinner('Generating response...'):
            response = chain({"question": prompt}, return_only_outputs=True)
            answer = response['answer']
            st.write(answer)
    else:
        st.warning('Please enter your prompt')
```

I also added `st.button`, `st.spinner`, and `st.warning` (optional)

Comment: Can I use it to create a tool to be used in a agent?

Comment: Do you know how I can solve this by running `arun()` asynchronously?