# `run` not supported when there is not exactly one output key. Got ['quiz', 'review']

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, langchain, huggingface, py-langchain

**My ERROR**

```
`run` not supported when there is not exactly one output key. Got ['quiz', 'review'].
```

**MY CODE**

**Libraries**

```
import os 
import json
import pandas as pd
import traceback
from  langchain import PromptTemplate , HuggingFaceHub ,LLMChain
from langchain.chains import SequentialChain
from dotenv import load_dotenv
```

**Loading my env and key**

```
load_dotenv()
key = os.getenv("hugging_face_key")
os.environ['HUGGINGFACEHUB_API_TOKEN'] = key
```

**Initializing My LLM model from HuggingFace**

```
llm=HuggingFaceHub(repo_id='google/flan-t5-base',model_kwargs={'temperature':0.5})
```

**My Prompt Template and Response : -** made a two chain 1.Quiz 2.review

```
RESPONSE_JSON = {
    "1": {
        "mcq": "multiple choice question",
        "options": {
            "a": "choice here",
            "b": "choice here",
            "c": "choice here",
            "d": "choice here",
        },
        "correct": "correct answer",
    },
    "2": {
        "mcq": "multiple choice question",
        "options": {
            "a": "choice here",
            "b": "choice here",
            "c": "choice here",
            "d": "choice here",
        },
        "correct": "correct answer",
    },
    "3": {
        "mcq": "multiple choice question",
        "options": {
            "a": "choice here",
            "b": "choice here",
            "c": "choice here",
            "d": "choice here",
        },
        "correct": "correct answer",
    },
}


TEMPLATE="""
Text:{text}
You are an expert MCQ maker. Given the above text, it is your job to \
create a quiz of {number} multiple choice questions for {subject} students in {tone} tone,
Make sure the question are not repeated and check all the questions to be conforming the text as well.
Make sure to format your response like RESPONSE_JSON below and use it as a guide. \
Ensure to make {number} MCQs
### RESPONSE_JSON
{response_json}

"""

quiz_generation_prompt = PromptTemplate(
    input_variables=["text","number","subject","tone","response_json"],
    template = TEMPLATE
)

quiz_chain=LLMChain(llm=llm,prompt=quiz_generation_prompt,output_key="quiz",verbose=True)

TEMPLATE2 = """
You are an expert english grammarian and writer . Given a Multiple Choice Quiz for {subject} students.\
You need to evaluate the complexity of the question and give a complete analysis of the quiz.Only use at max 50 words for complexity
if the quiz is not at per with the cognitive and analytical abilities of the students,\
update the quiz questions which needs to be changed and change the tone such that it perfectly fits the student abilities 
Quiz_MCQs:
{quiz}

Check from an expert English Writer of the above quiz:


quiz_evaluation_prompt = PromptTemplate(input_variables=["subject","quiz"],template=TEMPLATE2)


review_chain =LLMChain(llm=llm,prompt=quiz_evaluation_prompt,output_key="review",verbose=True)
```

**Making a Sequential Chain : -** For Executing both chain in sequence

```
generate_evaluate_chain=SequentialChain(chains=[quiz_chain,review_chain],input_variables=["text","number","subject","tone","response_json"],
                                        output_variables=["quiz","review"],verbose=True)
```

**Adding Data File:-**  Which contain Text of my Quiz

```
path = "C:\Hardik\Ai_tools\MCQ_Generator\data.txt"

with open(path,'r') as file:
    TEXT = file.read()
```

**Searialize the python dictionary into a json-formated string**

```
json.dumps(RESPONSE_JSON)
```

```
NUMBER = 5
SUBJECT = "machine learning"
TONE = "simple"
```

**Response** :- it runs the model and give the output

```
response = generate_evaluate_chain.run(text=TEXT, number=NUMBER, subject=SUBJECT, tone=TONE, response_json=json.dumps(RESPONSE_JSON))
```

**ERROR:** While Executing Response Cell it is giving me ValueError

**ValueError**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[39], line 1
----> 1 response = generate_evaluate_chain.run(text=TEXT, number=NUMBER, subject=SUBJECT, tone=TONE, response_json=json.dumps(RESPONSE_JSON), output_key='quiz')

File c:\Hardik\Ai_tools\MCQ_Generator\Mcq\lib\site-packages\langchain_core\_api\deprecation.py:145, in deprecated.<locals>.deprecate.<locals>.warning_emitting_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    143     warned = True
    144     emit_warning()
--> 145 return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)

File c:\Hardik\Ai_tools\MCQ_Generator\Mcq\lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\base.py:540, in Chain.run(self, callbacks, tags, metadata, *args, **kwargs)
    503 """Convenience method for executing chain.
    504 
    505 The main difference between this method and `Chain.__call__` is that this
   (...)
    537         # -> "The temperature in Boise is..."
    538 """
    539 # Run at start to make sure this is possible/defined
--> 540 _output_key = self._run_output_key
    542 if args and not kwargs:
    543     if len(args) != 1:

File c:\Hardik\Ai_tools\MCQ_Generator\Mcq\lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\base.py:488, in Chain._run_output_key(self)
    485 @property
    486 def _run_output_key(self) -> str:
...
    490             f"one output key. Got {self.output_keys}."
    491         )
    492     return self.output_keys[0]

ValueError: `run` not supported when there is not exactly one output key. Got ['quiz', 'review'].
```

I have go through the documentation as well and look for some solution stating to use predict in place of run but there is no function named predict in SequentialChain model

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: \`run\` not supported when there is not exactly one input key, got \['question', 'documents'\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76199653/valueerror-run-not-supported-when-there-is-not-exactly-one-input-key-got-q)

Comment: No that does not answer my Question but i found the solution .
 i have just used  get_openai_callback for calling the response it started generating